# object tree initialization using IoC

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm progarmming in C#/Silverlight.

In my case, I want some objects (e.g. some view models) to be constructed at runtime.

1. There are multiple instances for one class/interface.
2. Objects has some parent-child or hierarchical relationship (e.g. A has a property that returns a collection of B and B has a property that holds a collection of C... like a tree)
3. They need to be constructed according to **CONFIG file** (because we need different objects for different clients.)

Is this scenario suitable for IoC libraries?

If yes, before diving into too much details of each library, which looks like a good choice for me? Unity? Autofac? Ninject? I know many frameworks tend to be config-free but in my case I need something dynamic-config-friendly and collection-injection-friendly.

Thanks,

Comment: Asking which DI framework is best is not a good question for Stackoverflow, since this is highly subjective. Besides, you can often easily define (some) dependencies in XML, even for frameworks that have no XML based configuration support.

Answer (score 1):

No. Depending on the complexity you either want to use the Builder pattern or the Factory pattern.

You could use the service locator features of your container internally in the factory/build to locate all implementations.